# Как перевести научный формат записи чисел в традиционный в C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

В приложении WPF при построении графиков (LiveCharts) шкала по Y имеет диапазон от -1 до +1, но вместо 0 отображается число в формате 6,93889390390723Е-18, подскажите возможные решения данной задачи?
Сам диапазон шкалы, фреймворк устанавливает сам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<wpf:CartesianChart
            x:Name="Ploter"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
            LegendLocation="Right"
            MouseMove="ChartMouseMove"
            ScrollBarFill="Blue"
            Series="{Binding Chart1History}"
            Zoom="X">
            <wpf:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <wpf:Axis
                    x:Name="xAxis"
                    Title="{Binding UnitTitle}"
                    Labels="{Binding Labels}" />
            </wpf:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        </wpf:CartesianChart>
```

ViewModel

```
private string Name;
    public PloterViewModel(string Name, bool typeAxisX, int strokes)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.strokes = strokes;
        instance = this;
        Chart1History = new SeriesCollection();
        Labels = new string[] { };
        CreateDataGraphics(typeAxisX);
    }
    public SeriesCollection Chart1History
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue<SeriesCollection>(Chart1HistoryProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(Chart1HistoryProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData Chart1HistoryProperty = RegisterProperty("Chart1History", typeof(SeriesCollection), null);
    public string[] Labels
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue<string[]>(LabelsProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(LabelsProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData LabelsProperty = RegisterProperty("Labels", typeof(string[]), null);
    public string UnitTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue<string>(UnitTitleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(UnitTitleProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData UnitTitleProperty = RegisterProperty("UnitTitle", typeof(string), null);

    private void CreateDataGraphics(bool typeAxisX)
    {
        List<string> AxisX = new List<string>();
        if (typeAxisX)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < PloterServices.dataValue[Name].dataValue.First().Value.Meanings.Count; i++)
            {
                AxisX.Add((PloterServices.dataValue[Name].dataValue.First().Value.Meanings[i].date - PloterServices.StartTime).Minutes.ToString());
            }
            UnitTitle = "Minutes";
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < PloterServices.dataValue[Name].dataValue.First().Value.Meanings.Count; i++)
            {
                AxisX.Add(i.ToString());
            }
            UnitTitle = "Strokes";
        }
        int cnt = 0;
        foreach (var val in PloterServices.dataValue[Name].dataValue)
        {
            Chart1History.Add(new LineSeries { Values = new ChartValues<ObservableValue> { }, Title = val.Value.name, Fill = Brushes.Transparent });
            for (int j = 0; j < val.Value.Meanings.Count; j++)
            {
                    Chart1History[cnt].Values.Add(new ObservableValue(val.Value.Meanings[j].value));
            }
            cnt++;
        }
        Labels = AxisX.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Желателен код, т. к. не понятно какой тип chart Вы используете и как настраиваете его отображение. В [примере с их сайта](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Constant%20Changes%20II) всё хорошо.

Comment: Код предоставил

Comment: Могу лишь предположить что не так. Возможно это связано с тем, что включено отображение чисел в экспоненциальном виде. Проще будет взять пример использования этого chart с [github](https://github.com/Live-Charts/GearedExamples) и адаптировать под свой случай.

Comment: а приблизительно в каком месте можно посмотреть, или отключить данный параметр?